# Add analytics script after button click opt-in Next.js/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, onclick, gdprconsentform

How do I add/activate analytics scripts on a button click?

I have analytics scripts I need to add to a next.js website only if the user opts in.

On the click of a button in my `CookieBanner` component I set a cookie to record if they've opted in. At this point I also want to then append the script tags to the Head element:

### CookieBanner.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import cookie from "js-cookie";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function CookieBanner() {

    // // Set a cookie to hide the banner
    const [showBanner, setBanner] = useState(true);

    const handleBanner = (setOptIn) => {
        // Hide banner
        setBanner(false);

        // Set cookies
        updateGDPR(setOptIn);
    }

    function updateGDPR(gdprState) {
        gdprState ? cookie.set('gdprOptIn', true) : cookie.set('gdprOptIn', false);

        document.head.innerHTML += document.head.innerHTML + `
            <script>
                /* <!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for my site --> */
                (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
                    My Hotjar code here
                })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
                
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            
            gtag('config', 'G-MY G TAG HERE');
        </script>
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-MY G TAG HERE"></script>`

    return;
}

return (
    <div className={`cookie-banner ${!showBanner ? 'hide-banner' : ''}`} id="cookieBanner">
        <div className="cookie-card">
            <h1>Cookies</h1>
            <p>We’d like to use analytics cookies so we can understand how you use the website and make improvements.</p>
            <p>We also use essential cookies to remember if you’ve accepted analytics cookies. <Link href={'/privacy/cookies'}>Learn more</Link></p>
            <form className="button-wrapper">
                <button value={'accept'} type="button" className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{handleBanner(true)}}>Accept all</button>
                <button value={'reject'} type="button" className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{handleBanner(false)}}>Reject</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However nothing is then firing as I move around the site despite the tags being in place.

On a refresh or initial load everything works as it should. In this case the script tags being added in the _app.js file if opted in, which I know via a cookie that is set on the button click:

### App.js file (working):

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
        {pageProps.analytics.setAnalytics ? 
        <>
          <Head>
            {/* Hotjar */}
            <script
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ``
                /* <!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for my site --> */
                (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
                  CODE HERE
                })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');`
              }}
            />

            {/* Google Analytics */}
            <script
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
                `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());
                
                gtag('config', 'MY G TAG HERE');`}}
                />    
          </Head>
            
          <Script id='ga_tagmanager'
                  strategy='afterInteractive' 
                  async 
                  src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MY ID HERE"/>
        </>
        :''}

      {(pageProps.analytics == undefined || pageProps.analytics.showCookieBanner == true) && 
        <CookieBanner></CookieBanner> 
      }
      
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at first create script tag:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = `  /* <!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for my site --> */
                (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
                    My Hotjar code here
                })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
                
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            
            gtag('config', 'G-MY G TAG HERE');`
```

And then append it to head.

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```